# Best practice to list my Driver instance as static, especially for dual test execution?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Best practice to list my Driver instance as static, especially for dual test execution?**

**Driver factory** (Used to setup the driver instance):

```
public class DriverFactory  {
public static WebDriver driver;
protected BasePage basePage;
protected LoginPage loginPage;


public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
    try {
        ReadConfigFile file = new ReadConfigFile();
        String browserName = file.getBrowser();

        switch (browserName) {

        //firefox setup
        case "firefox":
            if (null == driver) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

**Steps class:** (Cucumber step class):

```
public class LoginSteps extends DriverFactory {

@Given("^User navigates to the \"([^\"]*)\" website$")
public void user_navigates_to_the_website(String url) throws Throwable {
    BasePage basePage = new BasePage();
    basePage.loadUrl(url);
}
```

}

**Base Page**(Base page for page objects):

```
public class BasePage extends DriverFactory {
protected WebDriverWait wait;
protected JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor;

public BasePage() throws IOException {
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    jsExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @sen4ik, if I make the webdriver variable non static, is parallel test execution even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. In my case i use WebDriver factory. You can read about it here [link](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-design-patterns-in-test-automation-factory-pattern/)

Comment: @sen4ik thanks for the link